# Android Checkable LinearLayout states

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I'am trying to implement a checkable Linear Layout, i already accomplish the checked item, but now the onclick and the onLongClick its not working has it should any ideas how can i implement this behavior.

- if unchecked && OnLongClick = check
- if checked && onClick = uncheck
- if checked && onLongClick = uncheck
- if unchecked && onClick = super.performClick()

My checkable LinearLayout

```
public class CheckableLinearLayout extends LinearLayout implements Checkable {

/**
 * Interface definition for a callback to be invoked when the checked state
 * of this View is changed.
 */
public static interface OnCheckedChangeListener {

    /**
     * Called when the checked state of a compound button has changed.
     * 
     * @param checkableView
     *            The view whose state has changed.
     * @param isChecked
     *            The new checked state of checkableView.
     */
    void onCheckedChanged(View checkableView, boolean isChecked);
}

private static final int[] CHECKED_STATE_SET = { android.R.attr.state_checked };

private boolean mChecked = false;

private OnCheckedChangeListener mOnCheckedChangeListener;

public CheckableLinearLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public boolean isChecked() {
    return mChecked;
}

public void setChecked(boolean b) {
    if (b != mChecked) {
        mChecked = b;
        refreshDrawableState();

        if (mOnCheckedChangeListener != null) {
            mOnCheckedChangeListener.onCheckedChanged(this, mChecked);
        }
    }
}

public void toggle() {
    setChecked(!mChecked);
}

@Override
public int[] onCreateDrawableState(int extraSpace) {
    final int[] drawableState = super.onCreateDrawableState(extraSpace + 1);
    if (isChecked()) {
        mergeDrawableStates(drawableState, CHECKED_STATE_SET);
    }
    return drawableState;
}

/**
 * Register a callback to be invoked when the checked state of this view
 * changes.
 * 
 * @param listener
 *            the callback to call on checked state change
 */
public void setOnCheckedChangeListener(OnCheckedChangeListener listener) {
    mOnCheckedChangeListener = listener;
}

@Override
public boolean performLongClick() {
    toggle();
    return super.performLongClick();
}

@Override
public boolean performClick() {

    if (isChecked()) {
        toggle();
        return false;
    } else
        return super.performClick();
}
```

my state drawable xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:drawable="@drawable/add_schedule_button_checked_pressed" android:state_checked="true" android:state_pressed="true"/>

<!-- <item android:drawable="@drawable/add_schedule_button_checked_focused" -->
<!-- android:state_checked="true" -->
<!-- android:state_focused="true" /> -->

<item android:drawable="@drawable/selected_card_shape_w_shadow_white" android:state_checked="true"/>

<!-- <item android:drawable="@drawable/add_schedule_button_unchecked_pressed" -->
<!-- android:state_pressed="true" /> -->


<!-- <item android:drawable="@drawable/add_schedule_button_unchecked_focused" -->
<!-- android:state_focused="true" /> -->
```

My layout

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/topics_preview_main_frame"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/favorites_header_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/favorites_header_title"
        style="@style/CardText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:background="@drawable/card"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:text="@string/favorites_header" />

    <ui.CheckableLinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/favorites_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:background="@drawable/selector_card_shape_w_shadow_white"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:longClickable="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="16dp" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:paddingRight="8dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/favorites_title"
                style="@style/CardTitle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="title" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:background="@color/C_Favorites_Pink" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/favorites_description_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="4dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/favorites_description"
                style="@style/CardText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:maxLines="4"
                android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ui.CheckableLinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

My fragment

```
private void onFavoriteClick(final MCourse courseInfo,
        LinearLayout favoritesLayout) {
    favoritesLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String courseId = Integer.toString(v.getId());
            String courseName = courseInfo.getFullname();

            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("courseId", courseId);
            bundle.putString("courseName", courseName);

            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager
                    .beginTransaction();

            TopicsPreview insideTopicsFrag = new TopicsPreview();
            insideTopicsFrag.setArguments(bundle);
            fragmentTransaction
                    .replace(R.id.mainFragment, insideTopicsFrag);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: if somebody wants to get full solution, check this repository: https://github.com/shamanland/AndroidLayoutSelector there is custom clickable/checkable ```LinearLayout``` like a ```ToggleButton```

Comment: And with this lib the checked drawable overlaps the full size of the layout!? check the problem [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19099467/android-selector-draw-doesnt-overlap)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in order to fix your current code, i've published here a whole code solution (since i didn't understand what's wrong with yours). it's quite similar, only it doesn't have the extra logic that you wanted.

alternatively, you can use the next solution instead:

you can call setOnClickListener and setOnLongClickListener on the CTOR , and have the logic in the new functions according to the current state, as such:

```
public CheckableLinearLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) 
  {
  super(context, attrs);
  setOnClickListener(null);
  }
```

in order to make the "outside world" work with these new methods, you need to make them as wrappers, for example:

```
public void setOnClickListener(... listener)
  {
  super.setOnClickListener(new ...
    {
    @Override
    public void onClick(...)
      {
      // TODO add add logic that you wanted according to the state of the view
      if(listener!=null) 
        listener.onClick(...);
      }
    });
  }
```

similar thing should be implemented for the long-clicking.

btw, you've forgot to add handling of the savedState bundle. read [**here**](https://gist.github.com/christopherperry/3746480) for the missing things .

here's my code that i've tested to work with the "checkability" of the layout:

```
public class CheckableLinearLayout extends LinearLayout implements Checkable
  {
  private boolean             mChecked;
  private static final String TAG               =CheckableLinearLayout.class.getCanonicalName();
  private static final int[]  CHECKED_STATE_SET = {android.R.attr.state_checked};

  public CheckableLinearLayout(final Context context)
    {
    super(context);
    setClickable(true);
    setLongClickable(true);
    }

  public CheckableLinearLayout(final Context context,final AttributeSet attrs)
    {
    super(context,attrs);
    setClickable(true);
    setLongClickable(true);
    }

  @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
  public CheckableLinearLayout(final Context context,final AttributeSet attrs,final int defStyle)
    {
    super(context,attrs,defStyle);
    setClickable(true);
    setLongClickable(true);
    }

  @Override
  public void setChecked(final boolean checked)
    {
    mChecked=checked;
    refreshDrawableState();
    }

  @Override
  protected int[] onCreateDrawableState(final int extraSpace)
    {
    final int[] drawableState=super.onCreateDrawableState(extraSpace+1);
    if(isChecked())
      mergeDrawableStates(drawableState,CHECKED_STATE_SET);
    return drawableState;
    }

  @Override
  protected void drawableStateChanged()
    {
    super.drawableStateChanged();
    final Drawable drawable=getBackground();
    if(drawable!=null)
      {
      final int[] myDrawableState=getDrawableState();
      drawable.setState(myDrawableState);
      invalidate();
      }
    }

  @Override
  public boolean performClick()
    {
    Toast.makeText(getContext(),"click",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return super.performClick();
    }

  @Override
  public boolean performLongClick()
    {
    Toast.makeText(getContext(),"long click",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return super.performLongClick();
    }

  @Override
  public boolean isChecked()
    {
    return mChecked;
    }

  @Override
  public void toggle()
    {
    setChecked(!mChecked);
    }

  @Override
  public Parcelable onSaveInstanceState()
    {
    // Force our ancestor class to save its state
    final Parcelable superState=super.onSaveInstanceState();
    final SavedState savedState=new SavedState(superState);
    savedState.checked=isChecked();
    return savedState;
    }

  @Override
  public void onRestoreInstanceState(final Parcelable state)
    {
    final SavedState savedState=(SavedState)state;
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedState.getSuperState());
    setChecked(savedState.checked);
    requestLayout();
    }

  // /////////////
  // SavedState //
  // /////////////
  private static class SavedState extends BaseSavedState
    {
    boolean                                            checked;
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public static final Parcelable.Creator<SavedState> CREATOR;
    static
      {
      CREATOR=new Parcelable.Creator<SavedState>()
        {
          @Override
          public SavedState createFromParcel(final Parcel in)
            {
            return new SavedState(in);
            }

          @Override
          public SavedState[] newArray(final int size)
            {
            return new SavedState[size];
            }
        };
      }

    SavedState(final Parcelable superState)
      {
      super(superState);
      }

    private SavedState(final Parcel in)
      {
      super(in);
      checked=(Boolean)in.readValue(null);
      }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(final Parcel out,final int flags)
      {
      super.writeToParcel(out,flags);
      out.writeValue(checked);
      }

    @Override
    public String toString()
      {
      return TAG+".SavedState{"+Integer.toHexString(System.identityHashCode(this))+" checked="+checked+"}";
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Let me see if i understood what you're saying, I've to put the setOnClick's listenen's in the constructor of this view?! I'am implementing the onclickListener in the fragment that inflate this layout. Can you please explain me better what you're saying. thanks ;)

Comment: i don't understand. anyway, i've updated my answer with a complete code that works. note in if you wish to handle the touch events even if the layout has children that are clickable, you have to override onInterceptTouchEvent and return there true.

Comment: Thanks @android you save my day :) you're the man who knows thanks once again

Comment: @firetrap did you find out what was the problem? which solution did you choose?

Comment: I had implemented "the missing things" you gave me and added my extras and everything starts to work, i will post my code in a update to help others, i didn't even tried your CTOR solution and wrappers, just because for me, the first approach seems more clean code. But now I've a design problem because only the child's are check-able so the draw will not fill the unchecked draw. [IMAGE](http://imgur.com/Rb9i3Gw)

Comment: i'm not sure i understand. do you want that each time the layout is checked/unchecked, all of the children will be checked too? if so, that's something i've actually removed from the code i had before. would you like me to add it too?

Comment: No its not that (i think), it's something in the image overlap; the second draw (the one in the selector) cant fully overlap the original one. Had you see the screenshot in my previous comment?! In the screenshot you will see some white borders from the original shape and that its odd, the grey one its from the selector draw, the draw from the selector should overlap the original but it's not doing that, perhaps some dark magic will work :p

Comment: I'm not sure what is the problem in this image as i don't know what you wish to achieve. would you please post a new question and describe it better and show some code and/or XML ? you can put here a link so that I will be able to help you there too.

Comment: this is what i was talking [my new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19099467/android-selector-draw-doesnt-overlap) take a look and see if you understand. thanks for all the help.