# Android selector draw doesn't overlap

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

My problem is when my `CheckableLinearLayout` is checked my draw from the selector can't overlap the unchecked image.

My `CheckableLinearLayout`

```
public class CheckableLinearLayout extends LinearLayout implements Checkable {
    private boolean mChecked;
    private static final String TAG = CheckableLinearLayout.class
            .getCanonicalName();
    private static final int[] CHECKED_STATE_SET = 
        { android.R.attr.state_checked };

    public CheckableLinearLayout(final Context context) {
        super(context);
        setClickable(true);
        setLongClickable(true);
    }

    public CheckableLinearLayout(final Context context, 
                                 final AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setClickable(true);
        setLongClickable(true);
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2)
    public CheckableLinearLayout(final Context context,
                                 final AttributeSet attrs, 
                                 final int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        setClickable(true);
        setLongClickable(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void setChecked(final boolean checked) {
        mChecked = checked;
        refreshDrawableState();
    }

    @Override
    protected int[] onCreateDrawableState(final int extraSpace) {
        final int[] drawableState = 
            super.onCreateDrawableState(extraSpace + 1);
        if (isChecked())
            mergeDrawableStates(drawableState, CHECKED_STATE_SET);
        return drawableState;
    }

    @Override
    protected void drawableStateChanged() {
        super.drawableStateChanged();
        final Drawable drawable = getBackground();
        if (drawable != null) {
            final int[] myDrawableState = getDrawableState();
            drawable.setState(myDrawableState);
            invalidate();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean performClick() {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if (isChecked()) {
            toggle();
            return false;
        } else
            return super.performClick();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean performLongClick() {
        toggle();
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "long click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return super.performLongClick();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChecked() {
        return mChecked;
    }

    @Override
    public void toggle() {
        setChecked(!mChecked);
    }

    @Override
    public Parcelable onSaveInstanceState() {
        // Force our ancestor class to save its state
        final Parcelable superState = super.onSaveInstanceState();
        final SavedState savedState = new SavedState(superState);
        savedState.checked = isChecked();
        return savedState;
    }

    @Override
    public void onRestoreInstanceState(final Parcelable state) {
        final SavedState savedState = (SavedState) state;
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedState.getSuperState());
        setChecked(savedState.checked);
        requestLayout();
    }

    // /////////////
    // SavedState //
    // /////////////
    private static class SavedState extends BaseSavedState {
        boolean checked;
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        public static final Parcelable.Creator<SavedState> CREATOR;
        static {
            CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<SavedState>() {
                @Override
                public SavedState createFromParcel(final Parcel in) {
                    return new SavedState(in);
                }

                @Override
                public SavedState[] newArray(final int size) {
                    return new SavedState[size];
                }
            };
        }

        SavedState(final Parcelable superState) {
            super(superState);
        }

        private SavedState(final Parcel in) {
            super(in);
            checked = (Boolean) in.readValue(null);
        }

        @Override
        public void writeToParcel(final Parcel out, final int flags) {
            super.writeToParcel(out, flags);
            out.writeValue(checked);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return TAG + ".SavedState{"
                    + Integer.toHexString(System.identityHashCode(this))
                    + " checked=" + checked + "}";
        }
    }
}
```

My **layout.xml**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/topics_preview_main_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/favorites_header_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/favorites_header_title"
            style="@style/CardText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:background="@drawable/card"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:text="@string/favorites_header" />

        <ui.CheckableLinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/favorites_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:background="@drawable/card_selector_w_shadow"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:longClickable="true"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="16dp" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                android:paddingRight="8dp" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/favorites_title"
                    style="@style/CardTitle"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="title" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:background="@color/C_Favorites_Pink" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/favorites_description_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="4dp" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/favorites_description"
                    style="@style/CardText"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:maxLines="4"
                    android:text="Lorem ipsum ..." />
            </LinearLayout>
        </ui.CheckableLinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

**card_selector_w_shadow**-> this draw will call the selector

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item>
        <shape
            android:dither="true"
            android:shape="rectangle" >
            <corners android:radius="2dp" />

            <solid android:color="#ccc" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:bottom="2dp">
        <shape
            android:dither="true"
            android:shape="rectangle" >
            <corners android:radius="2dp" />

            <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />

            <padding
                android:bottom="8dp"
                android:left="8dp"
                android:right="8dp"
                android:top="8dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/drawable_states"/>

</layer-list>
```

My **drawable_states**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/checked_background" 
          android:state_checked="true"/>
</selector>
```

This is what's happening:

[image]

This is what I intend:

[image]

I think this is because my `CheckableLinearLayout` only changes the state of the children, so the draw only overlap the children. Any advices?

Comment: where do you use "my_selector.xml" ? where is the drawable xml of "card_selector_w_shadow" ? maybe there you have the problem? try for example using @android:drawable/list_selector_background instead as its background and see if this will make the touching change the color of the background (it won't change according to checkability but this could act as an indication for what's wrong).

Comment: ok i've updated my question with the name of the files. i will give it a try ;) UPDATE: I've changed to @android:drawable/list_selector_background and it change the background as supposed (not checkability) but still don't fill.

Comment: please make sure in the DDMS with the hierarchy viewer that the view really covers the area that you need to fill.